# check for " in string vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, special-characters

I am struggling to check for a " in a string in vb.net. Could anybody suggest a way to look for " in string as we do in c# using  " \" "

I have tried with, \" and "" but of no use.

```
If partnerItem.Contains("*") Or partnerItem.Contains(""") Then
isBad = True
reportError(i + 1, colDetails(0), colDetails(1), "Field cannot contain " & PARTNER_ITEM_INVALID_CHARACTERS & " characters.")
```

Comment: Don't forget to use OrElse instead of Or to shortcut checks if a previous check returns what you are looking for.

Comment: this is to filter out invalid character in the sheet being uploaded in database, it the partnerItem contains " it should raise error

Comment: Ok. You don't need to do this. Instead convert the double quotes into 2 single quotes. This is what we do in vb.net

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
... partnerItem.Contains("""") ...
```

I believe VB.Net escapes double-quotes with double-quotes.  Thanks to the code-coloring on this site, your syntax is correctly highlighted with this change.

```
If partnerItem.Contains("*") Or partnerItem.Contains("""") Then
   isBad = True
   reportError(i + 1, colDetails(0), colDetails(1), "Field cannot contain " & PARTNER_ITEM_INVALID_CHARACTERS & " characters.")
```

Comment: And one of my least favorite language features of VB!

Comment: @14578446: You'll have to post the failing test case to get better help.

Comment: @14578446 Simply stating something "does not work" is not enough. If you want help, please tell us in what way it "does not work" by providing error messages, etc.

Comment: my bad, it was not working as i was using filter string like  partnerItem= Trim(filterString(holdingTank)). " was being filtered by it and the error was not being generated. Its working now on removing filterString. Thanks a lot all.

Answer (score 3):

You're really close, just short one `"`:

```
If partnerItem.Contains("*") Or partnerItem.Contains("""") Then
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can save strings with double quotes into the DB by replacing the double quotes with 2 single quotes or replace with nothing.

Replace with single quotes:

```
lsstr = lsstr.replace(chr(34),"'")
```

Replace with Nothing

```
Dim str As String = "I ""love"" VB"
Console.WriteLine(str)
Console.WriteLine(str.Replace("""", ""))
Catch ex As Exception
Console.Write(ex.ToString())
Finally
Console.Read()
```